# Creating new JS library - Help deciding the base structure

Tags: javascript, closures

Im creating a new library for a company. The structure I follow is

```
    (function() {
            var lib = function() {
                    //some private and public fn definitions

                    //setting publically avbl functions
                    return {
                    func1 : func1, func2: func2
                    };
            };
            return (window.lib = lib);
    })();
```

Now how I call this is

```
    lib.func1();
```

I want to be able to call my library as

```
    lib(function | string | object).someproperty
```

How do I convert my code. Tried something like this

```
    function lib() {
            return new arguments.callee(arguments);
    }

    lib.prototype={
            publicfunc: function() {
            }
    }
```

In this i'm having some problems accessing private functions since it is out of the scope for the public functions defined in the lib's prototype.

Comment: [General code layout (jQuery plugin specific but general enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980194/jquery-plugin-template-best-practice-convention-performance-and-memory-impact/6272580#6272580) and [Prototyping OO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337879/oop-programming-in-javascript-with-node-js/6339819#6339819)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lib = (function (param) {

   var func = function () {
     /// your code

     return {
         animate : function () {
          // do the animation
          return this;
     }
   }

   return func;
})();
```

this can be the basic fprmat.

ok here is how i can be used.

```
lib(function() {...});
```

or

```
lib(selectItem).animate();
```

because i returned `this` i can run another method if there is any.

```
lib(selectItem).animate().animate().animate().animate() ....;
```

i hope you can find a use of this format, of course i made it very basic

Comment: for `lib.myfunc` you can either use, lib.prototype.myfunc = function() ... , or u can lib.myfunc = func ...

Answer (score 0):

> In this i'm having some problems accessing private functions since it is out of the scope for the public functions defined in the lib's prototype.

This is because there is no such thing as `private` there is only `local`. You cannot access local variables out of scope.

The prototype cannot talk to local variables in the constructor. There are various hacks around this like keeping a public hash of instances but then you lose the "privacy"