# jQuery plugin template pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is this plugin pattern a good one ?

http://jsbin.com/isobar/12/edit

My goal was to have a global variable for each instance of the plugin, `base`, and the ability to call the same extern and intern method.

```
$('.my-plugin').myPlugin('myMethod', 'argument1', 'argument2');
or
base.myMethod('argument1', 'argument2');
```

Is there any specific compatibility problem or javascript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) and read this [jQuery plugin template - best practice, convention, performance and memory impact.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980194/jquery-plugin-template-best-practice-convention-performance-and-memory-impac)

Then start with this nice video: [jQuery Plugin development.](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/head-first-into-plugin-development/)