# How to chain jquery plugin option with regular jquery methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making a plugin called myPlugin (it is an object) and options object added to it as a property (hopefully I got that right) this way:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.options = {type: 'slideToggle'}
```

Now, inside a method within the myPlugin object, how would I change:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle(200);
```

so it gets the slideToggle from options, so it is not hardcoded ?

Something like:

```
$(this).next().myPlugin.options.type(200);
```

Comment: [jQuery plugin template - best practice, convention, performance and memory impact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980194/jquery-plugin-template-best-practice-convention-performance-and-memory-impac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do that with bracket notation, as that allows variables :

```
$(this).next()[self.options.type](200);
                 // ^^^ string that matches jQuery method, like slideToggle etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To chain you need to return the jQuery object(s) in your plugin so that it can be passed to the next method.

Like this:

```
 return this.each(function(){
        // element-specific code here
  });
```