# Could somebody tell me the benefits of making a jQuery plugin this verbose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins

What are the benefits? It's seems like an over-complicated way of doing things, so why wouldn't one just take a simple approach to building such a plugin, like that which is documented within [jQuery plugin docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)?

Please see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e2aYH/11/

Compared to..

```
jQuery.fn.placeKitten = function( options ) {

    // default settings:
    var defaults = {
        ...
    };

    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {
        // Plugin code to produce kitten image would go here...
    });

};
```

The author of this work also proceeded to say that he wouldn't bother with a jQuery plugin anyway, and they should never be used, but to make your code 'modularized' instead. Whatever that means if not via a jQuery plugin? and if it means not to use jQuery at all, I see a slew of benefits and efficiency when harnessing jQuery, so I also don't understand this remark.

Comment: Yes, it's too complicated. Developers should follow K.I.S.S. rule.

Comment: But it seems like such a useful plugin!

Comment: Is...is that plugin real? Is this real life?

Comment: any js code without tests is hard to understand.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy lol even your nickname is relevant for this question. No it's just a sample plugin demonstrating an apparently 'better' plugin design pattern, but I'm struggling to see benefits.

Comment: The benefits of it, vs what? that's the most basic form of a jQuery plugin.

Comment: The one in your question is near identical to the one mentioned in the docs. The only difference is the defaults are stored in a private var rather than in a location where they can be changed (which is a bad idea in my opinion, i prefer to be able to modify the defaults.)

Comment: @KevinB No sorry Kevin take a look at the JsFiddle at the top of the question, not my code sample. That's SO's fault for enforcing I have a code sample accompanying my JsFiddle.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that way of writing it at all. looks like complexity for the sake of complexity.

Comment: I'm sure it's doing some good things, but the way it's organized just makes it difficult to understand.